# A background URLSession with identifier already exists

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, nsurlsession, awss3transferutility, aws-sdk-ios

I have an S3Service which is a singleton that manages all the S3 related uploads and downloads.
When I upload the first image it works fine but if I try to upload an Image consecutively It gives me this warning and the completion block never gets called.

> A background URLSession with identifier `com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtility.Identifier.TransferManager` already exists.

This is how I upload method looks:

```
if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: S3Service.TRANSFER_MANAGER_KEY)
        transferUtility.uploadUsingMultiPart(data: data, bucket: EnvironmentUtils.getBucketName(), key: filename, contentType: "image/jpg", expression: nil, completionHandler: { task,error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Image upload success")
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: What does your singleton property look like?

Comment: @CalebKleveter It has the above mentioned code in an upload method, a method to register AWSS3 Transfer utility, and a method to unregister it.

Answer (score 5):

The call to register transfer utility `AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: serviceconfig, forKey: KEY)` was causing the above issue. There are two things that should be kept in mind.

- The `AWSS3TransferUtility` should be registered only once per Application session. Then we can use `AWSS3TransferUtility.S3TransferUtilityForKey` to get the instance wherever needed.
- If these are for different users within the app, ( e.g. sign-up) and if we want to keep `AWSS3TransferUtility` separate for each user, register `AWSS3TransferUtility` with a different key (preferably the same key for the same user) and look up using that key.